# Does Newton-Leibnitz apply to Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces

For a function $u\in W^{1,p}$, we always use a sequence of $C^1$ function to approach it and derive the consequences. However, can we just claim for a.e. x, y:

$$u(x)-u(y)= \int_0^1 Du(y+t(x-y))\cdot (x-y) dt$$

I tried to prove that it’s right in the following way:

Consider a $C^1$ sequence $u_n$ approaching u in $W^{1,p}$, the key here is to prove:

$$\int_0^1 D(u-u_n)(y+t(x-y))\cdot (x-y) dt$$

Tends to 0 as n tend to infinity, as we have, for a.e. x:

$$u_n(x) \to u(x)$$

Therefore, we have, for a.e. x, y:

$$ u(x)-u(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n(x)-u_n(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 Du_n(y+t(x-y))\cdot (x-y) dt= \int_0^1 Du(y+t(x-y))\cdot (x-y) dt$$

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona Do you mean using the $H^1$ in dimension 1 to derive it’s $C^{0,\alpha}$.  Then use the differentiability a.e. to show the formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Tends to 0 as n tend to infinity, which can be derived from the definition.

Derived how? There is no fault in your proof, just non-trivial detailsare missing.

The formula is however, true. The best way to think about Sobolev functions in $W^{1,p}$ is through the absolute continuity on lines:

[image]

Since we can rotate the coordinate directions you have absolute continuity on lines parallel to any coordinate direction. since the absolutely continuous functions satisfy the integration by parts formula, your formula for $u(x)-u(y)$ follows.

Theorem 2.23 quoted above is the same as Theorem 2 in Section 4.9.2 in the book aby Evans and Gariepy, although the statement there is less intuitive that the above one. For the above statement see "Cortona lectures" available on my webpage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I’ve followed the way you told to prove it and it’s amazing. By the way, I’ve just updated my proof above, would it be a proof now?

Comment: @user734979 It is correct provided if you are aware that you are using the Fubini theorem in your argument. I still like to think about Sobolev functions in terms of absolute continuity on lines since it gives you many results directly without necessity of approximation.

Comment: I’ve never learned this property before. As you said, it’s a totally different way to think about Sobolev functions and it’s so amazing. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thank you for this exposition. However, I am wondering how this can be compatible with the fact that there are nowhere differentiable functions in Sobolev spaces. For example: https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2021/fs/401-3462-00L/sc/extras/Nowhere_differentiable_Sobolev.pdf
Can you comment on that?

Comment: @shuhalo You can find functions in $W^{1,n}$ that there are nowhere continuous and hence they cannot be differentiable at any point. However, existence of partial derivatives does not imply differentiability or even continuity. No contradiction here. The characterization os Sobolev spaces through absolute continuity on lines is the best geometric characterization you can get.